# changing the font in KOMA class for a quotation

Tags: fonts, koma-script

I use the KOMA `\documentclass[12pt,captions=nooneline,DIV=14, parskip=half]{scrartcl}`class and I have a simple question.

In the text, I would like to use quotations like ``this is a quotation''.
That is the quotation is blended with the current text (no use of the quotation environment).

To better differentiate the quotation from the rest of the text, I would like to use a different font for it (possibly from http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/). How can I do it?

Many thanks!

Comment: I think you might be on the search for packagge enquote.

Comment: @Johannes_B: You mean csquotes?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes of course, thanks for noticing.

Comment: btw: You should rephrase the question. This is not limited to KOMA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Package `csquotes` does a great job handling all sorts of quotes
and does some magic choosing the language appropiate marks.

The package provides hooks to change the appearance of textquotes
and blockquotes, but a for `enquote` seems to be missing. I
copied the definition of the outer quote level (quotes can be
nested) and added a font switch. The inner level will now have
the same font.

I hope i just overlooked something and somebody comes up with a
better solution.

If you want to change the appearance of text and block quotes,
please use the appropriate hooks.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,captions=nooneline,DIV=14,parskip=half]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english,french,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[autostyle=true]{csquotes}
\newcommand*{\quotefont}{\fontfamily{Quattrocento-TLF}\selectfont}
\makeatletter
\long\def\csq@quote@i#1#2#3{%
    \csq@bqgroup#1\quotefont\csq@oqopen@i#3\csq@qclose@i{#2}}
\makeatother
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\enquote{Ein nettes kleines Zitat} und ein wenig \blindtext

\selectlanguage{french}
\enquote{Une citation jolie} et un peu \blindtext

\selectlanguage{english}
\enquote{A nice little quote}, a german cite
\foreignquote{ngerman}{Enten sind toll} and a bit \blindtext
\enquote{How about \enquote{nested} quotes?}
\textquote{How do i look like?}
\end{document}
```

Comment: thank you johannes! but how can I use another font? lets say this one http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/quattrocento/ ? Many thanks again! I already use another font from this catalogue for the main text

Comment: Replace the argument of `fontfamily`with `Quattrocento-TLF`.